# Why it prints elements after leaving a space at the beginning of the new line?

Tags: python-2.7

I am using python 2.7

this is a very easy code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
my_list = [1,2,3,4]

for i in my_list:
#    print(i)
    print(i, end="\n ")
#    print(i)
```

when I print this loop by:

```
print(i, end="\n ")
```

output:

```
1
 2
 3
 4
```

how to solve this issue using  this mothed not `print(i)`  becuase I  collect data by the robot without `for_loop`. So, I use this code for simplicity

when I need to write the data in the file, I am using `end="\n "`

it is leaving a space at the beginning of the new line

please help me or any suggestion

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra space is due to the space you passed in end argument in print function.
instead of `print(i, end="\n ")`
use`print(i, end="\n")`
Remember that whatever you pass inside double quotes will be displayed as it is on the terminal, so remove that extra space in "\n ".

Comment: thank you so so much, I don't focus about this wrong, it is fine now